# How to find first frequency value in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with objects. I need to find first repeating value in my loop. I think i need to use break but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
var arrWithNumbers = [2,4,5,2,3,5,1,2,4];
var firstIndex = 0;

for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  if(arrWithNumbers.length == firstIndex[i]) {
    firstIndex = arrWithNumbers;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(firstIndex);
```

Comment: I fail to understand your attempt... a number (index) doesn't have numeral properties like an array...

Comment: this program is only looking for first value(2), if 3 was repeating first it will not work... you need one more loop

Comment: by the way do you need 1st position(index) or recurrence or the value ... 2 here as per example ?

Comment: Some comments above give helpful clues - conceptually, you want to iterate over all items in `arrWithNumbers`. While you do that you want to search the whole array again for each item, to see if you can find a second, equal item. That'd be the straight-forward approach. If you're interested in the value of the first redundant item only you could sort the array, then step through comparing each value to its previous, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop until you get an index of the same number right of the actual index.

This proposal uses [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with a `fromIndex` greater than the actual index.

```js
var array = [2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4],
    index = 0,
    second;
    
while (index < array.length) {
    second = array.indexOf(array[index], index + 1);
    if (second !== -1) {
        break;
    }
    index++;
}

console.log(index);
console.log(second);
```

A hash table approach

```js
var array = [2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4],
    index = 0,
    hash = Object.create(null);
    
while (index < array.length) {
    if (array[index] in hash) {
        break;
    }
    hash[array[index]] = index;
    index++;
}

console.log(hash[array[index]], index);
```

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: Being devils advocate, this solution will perform poorly on a long array of unique elements.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore, right, with a hash table, or a solution like yours with a map, it is more performant than using `indexOf` all over again.

Answer (score 1):

I would leverage the native JS [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object and iterate over the array until we find an item we've already encountered by adding new elements to the map.

By using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) we only have to loop over the array once in the worst case, and by using Map we minimise our lookup time.

```js
const arr  = [2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4];

let m = new Map();

const firstDuplicate = arr.find(x => {
  if (m.has(x)){
    return true;
  } else {
    m.set(x, 1);
  };
});

console.log(firstDuplicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

A general programming way (not js way) would be something like this.

```
var arrWithNumbers = [2,4,5,2,3,5,1,2,4];
var firstIndex = '';
var foundNum = false;

for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  for(var j=i+1; j<10; i++) {
      if(arrWithNumbers[i] == arrWithNumbers[j]) {
         firstIndex = arrWithNumbers[i];
         break;
      }
   }
      if(foundNum)
         break;
}
```

Comment: To add to this, this is a very very beginners way of doing the programming.

Comment: but couild have simplified using index of... whose indexOf is lower.. take it ;)

Comment: @Alice indexOf is available in js and not in java. I just gave a general solution. Internally, indexOf does the same ;)

Comment: console.log in question, seems javascript